# How do I insert a 'section' at the top of IniFile via Ruby

Tags: ruby, ini

I have an Ini file, and I am using [IniFile](https://github.com/TwP/inifile) to help parse it. 
I want to add a new `section` at the top of the ini file, how do I do this?

---

sample.ini

```
[Student1]
A = 1

[Student2]
B = 1
```

---

My expected result,

```
[Summary]
NumOfStudents=2

[Student1]
A = 1

[Student2]
B = 1
```

---

Problem: the `Summary` section is always inserted at bottom.

```
[Student1]
A = 1

[Student2]
B = 1

[Summary]
NumOfStudents=2
```

---

My Ruby script

```
iniFileHandle = IniFile.load(sample.ini)
numOfStudents = iniFileHandle.sections.size

iniFileHandle['Summary'] = {'NumOfStudents' => numOfStudents}
```

---

Additional 
[Ruby IniFile 2.0.2 Doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/i/inifile-2.0.2/IniFile.html)
From the doc, I don't find any functions to insert a section at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Why is the order of the sections in an ini file relevant?

2)
my_prog.rb:

```
require 'inifile'

ini_file = IniFile.load("sample.ini")
numOfStudents = ini_file.sections.size

h = {
  "Summary" => { "NumOfStudents" => numOfStudents }
}

ini_file.instance_eval do
  p @ini                   #instance_eval() changes self to ini_file, and
  h.merge! @ini            #all instance variables are looked up in whatever
  @ini = h                 #object is self.  If you look at the inifile gem's source
end                        #code, the sections of the ini file are stored in a
                           #hash called @ini
ini_file.write

--output:--
$ cat sample.ini
[Student1]
A = 1

[Student2]
B = 1

~/ruby_programs$ ruby my_prog.rb 
{"Student1"=>{"A"=>"1"}, "Student2"=>{"B"=>"1"}}


~/ruby_programs$ cat sample.ini
[Summary]
NumOfStudents = 2

[Student1]
A = 1

[Student2]
B = 1
```

3) Or you can do it this way:

```
require 'inifile'

class IniFile
  attr_accessor :ini
end

ini_file = IniFile.load("sample.ini")
numOfStudents = ini_file.sections.size


h = {
  "Summary" => { "NumOfStudents" => numOfStudents }
}

results = h.merge! ini_file.ini
ini_file.ini = results

ini_file.write
```

Comment: Sure, you could also just write `class IniFile; attr_accessor :ini; end`, and then you can change @ini to your hearts content--I added that to my answer.

Comment: marked && up voted. For your first question, the ini file probably opens manually to find out how many students. If the `summary` section is always at the bottom, it's not convenient. And the section `StudentXX` already indicate how many students, therefore, It is not meaningful to put it at bottom.

Comment: I don't think ini files are supposed to be used for casual viewing--or providing summary information.  They are supposed to be used for initializing some configurations necessary for a program to run.

Comment: yes,mostly we don't directly open it, just in few cases which I encounter.

Answer (score 4):

The code of this gem is really simple, it is [only one file](https://github.com/TwP/inifile/blob/master/lib/inifile.rb).

It doesn't seems to be possible right now. You can implement this feature if you need it. In his code, basically he keep a section name and a hash with the variables on that section. what the `[]=` method does is to add a new variable to the hash using its `[]=` method. Since ruby 1.9 ruby hashes are ordered, but this method adds on the tail of it. A way to add in the front of the hash is like the following:

```
 {front_key: "Front value"}.merge(original_hash)
```

Happy hacking.

Comment: thanks. I got what you mean, let me do it later on, as I just learned ruby for one day. Up vote your idea.